# What's the proper way to add JSP & Servlet libs to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, jetty

I'm just starting out with Java web development using Eclipse. I'm playing with Jetty for JSP & Servlet.

Installed Eclipse Kepler Java EE IDE - it came with tomcat and other servers adapters but not Jetty. I know there are jetty plugins but I'm not interested in them.

When I create a new dynamic web project and create a new servlet, my file comes with the import statements and class structure.
Those imports fail saying cannot resolve class name.

It's because of eclipse not having the servlet & jsp API jars. I have the jetty 9.1.1 distribution and I added the jar lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar & lib/jsp/jsp-api-something.jar

The thing works now. But is this the correct way or there's some other way which can be helpful when developing more web projects because this library addition essentially for this project alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to get those libraries from the server you plan to run on, and to target that server with your Dynamic Web Project. The Java EE Preview Server *is* Jetty, so just choose it in the part of the wizard that you used to create the project.

[image: First page of the New Dynamic Web Project wizard]

You shouldn't add those jars specifically into your web project.  *Every* app server already has their own versions, and the copies you embed will just cause odd conflicts and misbehavior.

Comment: Epic. That solved the problem of me having to add them manually. The only thing that disturbs me now is that Jetty 9.1.1 is API 3.1 while eclipse gives me option only for 3.0 - that wont be much of an issue since I'm just starting out with Java and stuff, but is there a solution to this?

Comment: The Kepler packages contain Jetty 8.1, which I believe only supports 3.0. Hopefully you'll see that increased in Luna.

Comment: Got it.. anyway, I prefer using latest versions most of the time. I dug up some stuff and setup ant in eclipse such that it will generate a war into my jetty docroot. I've to just start jetty manually once whenever I want to develop :)

Answer (score 0):

the best thing to do is to add your jar files to the libs folder within your project ,

then go to your project properties , java build path , add jar files , browse and select the jar file the you want to import into your project .

Hope that helps .

Comment: That's what I've done currently. I created a user library with two jars and added the library to java build path.